# PHP Replacing Character Inside String With Variable

Tags: php, string, str-replace

In few words, I am trying to replace all the "?" with the value inside a variable and it doesn't work. Please help.

```
    $string = "? are red ? are blue";
    $count = 1;

    update_query($string, array($v = 'violets', $r = 'roses'));


    function update_query($string, $values){

        foreach ( $values as $val ){

            str_replace('?', $val, $string, $count);    
        }

        echo $string;
    }
```

The output I am getting is: ? are red ? are blue

Comment: How is it not working; define what errors you may be getting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not working meaning, no errors and the output is `? are red ? are blue`

Comment: You're not assigning the `str_replace` result anywhere. Also research preg_replace_callback instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys here is the solution from a combination of some good posts.

```
$string = "? are red ? are blue";

update_query($string, array($v = 'violets', $r = 'roses'));

function update_query($string, $values){

    foreach ( $values as $val ){

        $string = preg_replace('/\?/', $val, $string, 1);

    }

    echo $string;
}
```

As mentioned, `preg_replace` will allow limiting the amount of matches to update. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Frustrated by people not paying attention, I am compelled to answer the question *properly*.

`str_replace` will replace ALL instances of the search string. So after `violets`, there will be nothing left for `roses` to replace.

Sadly `str_replace` does not come with a limit parameter, but `preg_replace` does. But you can actually do better still with `preg_replace_callback`, like so:

```
function update_query($string, $values){
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($_) use (&$values) {
        return array_shift($values);
    }, $string);
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: thank you but this seem overly complex and `str_replace` does have a fourth parameter which limits the replacements, `from PHP's Docs: " count

    If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed."`

Comment: Read it again, @user3704920. It is SET to the number PERFORMED. It is NOT a "limit" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set it equal to your variable.

```
$string = str_replace('?', $val, $string, $count);
```

Comment: @dmikester1 even if I declare count inside the function, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to capture the return from str_replace in a new string and echo it for each replacement, and pass $count by reference.

```
   foreach ( $values as $val ){

        $newString = str_replace('?', $val, $string, &$count);    
        echo $newString;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and cleanest way to do it

```
  <?php

  $string = "? are red ? are blue";
  $string = str_replace('?','%s', $string);
  $data = array('violets','roses');

  $string = vsprintf($string, $data);  

  echo $string;
```

### Your code edited

```
$string = "? are red ? are blue";

update_query($string, array('violets','roses'));


function update_query($string, $values){

  $string = str_replace('?','%s', $string);
  $string = vsprintf($string, $values);

    echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways:

1) Substitute the question marks with their respective values. There are a hundred ways one could tackle it, but for something like this I prefer just doing it the old-fashioned way: Find the question marks and replace them with the new values one by one. If the values in `$arr` contain question marks themselves then they will be ignored.

```
function update_query($str, array $arr) {
    $offset = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $newVal) {
        $mark = strpos($str, '?', $offset);
        if ($mark !== false) {
            $str = substr($str, 0, $mark).$newVal.substr($str, $mark+1);
            $offset = $mark + (strlen($newVal) - 1);
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
$string = "? are red ? are blue";
$vars = array('violets', 'roses');
echo update_query($string, $vars);
```

2) Or you can make it easy on yourself and use unique identifiers. This makes your code easier to understand, and more predictable and robust.

```
function update_query($str, array $arr) {
    return strtr($str, $arr);
}
echo update_query(':flower1 are red :flower2 are blue', array(
    ':flower1' => 'violets',
    ':flower2' => 'roses',
));
```

You could even just use `strtr()`, but wrapping it in a function that you can more easily remember (and which makes sense in your code) will also work.

Oh, and *if* you are planning on using this for creating an SQL query then you should reconsider. Use your database driver's prepared statements instead.